# Playing sound in cocos2d game

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, cocos2d-iphone, simpleaudioengine

I'm checking code of a build game by another developer. You can understand how tuf it is. :)

I have to make a change in its sound.

When game is running the background sound remain same till game is over.

My task is to change sound after a specific time.

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:@"background.wav" loop:TRUE];
```

This piece of code is used by the old developer.

I don't know how to make chnage according to my need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yea! difficult task indeed! :)

Does a function is calling at the time you want to stop the background music? Like game paused, game over etc. In that case use this.

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] stopBackgroundMusic];
```

After that you can change to another background or do whatever.